# How to add new line within copying existing line in Vuejs - Laravel project

Tags: vuejs2, laravel-5.7

Here is my code.
When click "Add New Line" button, adding a blank line fine.
But, I need to adding copy existing line data within new table line.
Please help me.

```js
  

  addMarkerLine(){
        this.form.markeratios.push({
              size:null,
              ratio:0,
         })
      },
```

```html
    <form action="">
     <table>
     <thead>
     <tr>
        <th>SL.</th>
        <th>Size</th>
        <th>Ratio</th>
        <th>Action</th>
    </tr>`enter code here`
    </thead>
    <tbody>
     <tr v-for="(markeratio , index) in form.markeratios ">
        <td >{{index + 1}}</td>
        <td ><input type="text" v-model="markeratio.size"></td>
        <td ><input type="text" v-model="markeratio.ratio"></td>
        <td><button>Copy This Line</button></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
   <tr>
      <td><span @click="addMarkerLine">Add New Line</span></td>
   </tr>
   </tfoot>
 </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you explain what you want in more details or clarify your question.

Comment: Here i used push method to add new line that's work fine. But I need copy my existing line and past in new line instate of adding blank line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to copy the data into the next row, you just have to define a function `copyRow` that accepts an `object` data and when your `Copy This Line` button is clicked, pass the current object to `copyRow` function. In that function, just push the data to the `form.markeratios`.

```
<template>
  ...
  <tr v-for="(markeratio , index) in form.markeratios ">
    <td >{{index + 1}}</td>
    <td ><input type="text" v-model="markeratio.size"></td>
    <td ><input type="text" v-model="markeratio.ratio"></td>
    <td><button @click="copyRow(markeratio)">Copy This Line</button></td>
  </tr>
  ...
</template>

<script>
export default {
  ...
  data: {
    return {
      form: {
        markeratios: []
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    copyRow(data) {
      this.form.markeratios.push(data);
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for above solution, But there is facing problem that, when i clicked the copy button, line is copying & when change or inserting some data, all copied lines data is changing. Can you please give a solution for this?

Comment: I just made a fiddle for you. https://jsfiddle.net/9sLdmbz5/ . Seems all working fine on my end. It's better to share your code as well so that we can debug it together.